# The number of requests sent to the query

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller to sort users

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<List<User>> getUsers(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String q,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "1") int page,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "1") int pageSize,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "id") String sort
) {
    return Optional
            .ofNullable(q)
            .map(v -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.findByUsernameContaining(q, page - 1, pageSize, new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, sort))))
            .orElseGet(() ->
                    ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.findAll(page - 1, pageSize, new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, sort)))
            );
}
```

Which can take as parameter 4 values. It does not look too aesthetically and I wonder how it can be improved visually.

1. I was wondering about creating a class with these four variables, and then creating a method registered @ModelAttribute. However, I quickly gave it up because I will not be able to set 'defaultValue' as necessary.
2. The way I came up with this was to leave the parameter 'id' and the other three to make the 'Pegeable' object appended with '@PageableDefault' with the values set to 'size = 1, page = 1, sort = "id". However, this method also will not pass, because I necessarily need to subtract 1 from the value of 'page' when passing the page number to the site, and in this case it is impossible.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I personally see no problem in having many `@RequestParam` as you described.

Think about the advantages:

- it is crystal clear
- it is easy to test

Now the disadvantage:

- it is verbose

To me the advantages outweigh the disadvantages. Unless I am missing something.